# Django urls not working

Tags: django, url

I've been working with django for a short time and I'm new at it. I've encountered a problem with the urls.py file - here is the code:

```
url(r'^(?P<city>\w+)/(?P<main_type>\w+)/(?P<sub_type>\w+)/(?P<post_title_slug>\w+)$', 'postpage'),
```

When I redirect (for example) to `website.com/Paris/Art/Graphics/Test-title-for-slug`

It won't work - Page not found appears. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using: Django 1.4.1

Comment: Have you set APPEND_SLASH=True in settings.py https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: If you quickly change the '$' to '/?$' and it works, then your problem is with trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help but I solved it - Here is the solution:

The post_title_slug was badly formatted so instead of `(?P<post_title_slug>\w+)` I used this `(?P<post_title_slug>[-\w]+)`

Thanks again, hope this will help someone.